# Use the chain's rule to find $f'(x,y,z)$ if $f(x,y,z)=\int_{\sin x}^{yz} g(t)dt$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, chain-rule

Let $g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous and $f:\mathbb{R}^{3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined for $f(x,y,z)=\int_{\sin x}^{yz} g(t)dt$. Express $f$ like the composition of differentiable functions and use the chain's rule to find $f'(x,y,z)$,

I think the functions are $H(x,y,z) = (\sin x,y,z)$, $G(x,y,z)= \int_{x}^{yz} g(t)dt$, so $f(x,y,z)= G \circ H$.
Did I choose the correct functions?
Can you help me with the chain's rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, that's true, but not very useful (if this is your first time seeing this stuff). Instead, consider
\begin{align}
F(\xi):= \int_0^{\xi}g(t)\,dt.
\end{align}
Then,
\begin{align}
f(x,y,z)&=\int_0^{yz}g(t)\,dt - \int_0^{\sin x}g(t)\,dt\\
&=F(yz)-F(\sin x)
\end{align}
So, define $\phi_1(x,y,z)=yz$ and $\phi_2(x,y,z)=\sin x$. Then,
\begin{align}
f(x,y,z)&=(F\circ\phi_1)(x,y,z)-(F\circ \phi_2)(x,y,z)
\end{align}
So, what does the chain rule tell you now? Note that for differentiating $F$, the fundamental theorem of calculus is useful (assuming of course $g$ is continuous).

Comment: $g$ is continuous I forgot to write it. For the fundamental theorem of calculus $f_{x}= \frac{dF(\phi_{1})}{dx} \frac{\partial \phi_{1}}{\partial x}- f_{x}= \frac{dF(\phi_{2})}{dx} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}=0-g(\sin(x)) \cdot cos x $, for $f_{y}= zg(yz)$ and $f_{z}= yg(yz)$.